# Access USB flash driver files in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

Is it possible to access the files of USB flash driver in browsers ? ( chrome / firefox , etc ...)

first I've tried to detect the flash driver in chrome :

I can see my flash driver device in **chrome://device-log/** and **chrome://usb-internals/** but when I run this in console to see my flash driver , it can't be found ! it has detected my mouse and keyboard but not the flash driver !

```
navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [] })
.then(device => {
  console.log(device.productName);      
  console.log(device.manufacturerName); 
})
.catch(error => { console.error(error); });
```

Comment: It would be a big security issue if this was possible.

Comment: look like somehow it is not possible ... I've searched a lot but it came to nothing

Comment: Good, imagine any website being able to access your file system.

Comment: are you running in a secure contex (HTTPS)? according to the docs, that might be your issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB/requestDevice